# Get Dates of the Last 7 Days in Array In Custom Format

Tags: php, datetime

How do I get the exact dates of the last 7 days including today in a custom format (dd/mm)?

In the resulting array I would like to get something like (dates are examples only):

```
1=>11/2 (today minus 7 days)
2=>12/2 (today minus 6 days)
...
7=>17/2 (today)
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
function getLastNDays($days, $format = 'd/m'){
    $m = date("m"); $de= date("d"); $y= date("Y");
    $dateArray = array();
    for($i=0; $i<=$days-1; $i++){
        $dateArray[] = '"' . date($format, mktime(0,0,0,$m,($de-$i),$y)) . '"'; 
    }
    return array_reverse($dateArray);
}
```

Usage:

```
$arr = getLastNDays(7);
```

or

```
$arr = getLastNDays(7, 'd/m/Y');
```

Answer (score 10):

You can combine the 2 functions date() and strtotime(). for example:

```
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("7 days ago"));
```

Try:

```
for ($i=0; $i<7; $i++)
{
    echo date("d/m", strtotime($i." days ago")).'<br />';
}
```

You should be able to work out how to get them in the correct order and into an array :)

Hope that helps

Answer (score 5):

[time()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) gives you the current timestamp.
`86400` seconds are one day (60 * 60 * 24).
[date()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) gives you a custom date string.

```
for ($iDay = 6; $iDay >= 0; $iDay--) {
    $aDays[7 - $iDay] = date('d/m', time() - $iDay * 86400);
}
```

Also see [this example](http://ideone.com/POBCD).

If you don't want the leading zeros, use `'j/n'` as [custom date format parameter](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters):

```
for ($iDay = 6; $iDay >= 0; $iDay--) {
    $aDays[7 - $iDay] = date('j/n', time() - $iDay * 86400);
}
```

Also see this [updated example](http://ideone.com/a6Yzh).

=== UPDATE ===

@Dagon's idea to use [strtotime()](http://de3.php.net/strtotime) to get the timestamp is great. Here the better solution:

```
for ($iDay = 6; $iDay >= 0; $iDay--) {
    $aDays[7 - $iDay] = date('j/n', strtotime("-" . $iDay . " day"));
}
```

And [an example](http://ideone.com/Le2a2).

Comment: not all fays are 86400 long better to to use strtotime("-1 day")

Comment: there are leap seconds as well as leap days

Comment: @Dagon: Yes, your solution is more accurate. But leap days make no difference for the example above and [leap seconds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second) may be neglected because of their rarity.

Comment: "The next leap second will be inserted on June 30, 2012 at 23:59:60 UTC." that's not rare that's kind of soon!

Comment: Dagon is right. Consider this case. At the moment it’s `Today 23:55`. In 5 PM earlier this day DST rules changed clock **-1 hour** so this day is 1 hour longer and have 25 hours, not 24. That means 86400s ago is `Today 00:55` not `Yesterday 23:55`.

Comment: @Wh1T3h4Ck5: ok, the not previously mentioned DST rules are a very good example.